# Why each normal mode is treated as a harmonic oscillator in Debye's calculation of specific heat?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, lattice-model, phonons, normal-modes

So in Einstein's calculation of specific heat each oscillator is assumed to be vibrating with same frequency and its average energy is given by hv(n+1/2) where n is bose factor. Debye said that collective vibrations should be treated as sound wave propogating through the lattice.Now in debye's calculation as given in Oxford solid state physics book by Steven Simons each standing wave is treated as a harmonic oscillator and average internal energy is calculated by summing energies of each possible standing wave treated as a harmonic oscillator?Why each standing wave is treated as a harmonic oscillator here?

Comment: This is explained later on in Simons' book, in Chapter 9. In particular, some of the exercises. The idea is that you can transform the Hamiltonian of a set of coupled oscillators into a form that looks exactly like a set of decoupled oscillators, and so it can be quantized in the same way (these decoupled oscillators are exactly the normal modes).

Comment: Oh man! Thanks. I wasted so much time in this.

Comment: @march one more thing,it might sound silly, in calculation of total energy we multiply number of modes for a frequency by average energy for that mode and integrate over all possible frequencies so does that mean in some part crystal there is wave of wavevector k1 and in some other part k2? Or does that mean at a particular time there is wave of wavevector k1 propogating throughout the crystal and at some other time wave might be of wavevector k2 throughout the crystal?

Comment: The normal modes are delocalized across the entire lattice. If one of these modes is populated, that means the *entire lattice* is vibrating in the way specified by the normal mode (the (very close to exact) analogy here is to standing waves on a string, which is an example of a normal mode, just in a continuous medium). This is not quite right (QM/SM being what they are), but you can think of these normal modes being all populated (with amplitude given by Boltzmann factors) at once, with the entire lattice undergoing a complicated collective vibration that is a sum of all of these modes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that you can transform the Hamiltonian of a set of coupled oscillators into a form that looks exactly like a set of decoupled oscillators, and so it can be quantized in the same way. These decoupled oscillators are exactly the normal modes.

The normal modes are delocalized across the entire lattice. If one of these modes is populated, that means the entire lattice is vibrating in the way specified by the normal mode (the (very close to exact) analogy here is to standing waves on a string, which is an example of a normal mode, just in a continuous medium). This is not quite right (QM/SM being what they are), but you can think of these normal modes being all populated (with amplitude given by Boltzmann factors) at once, with the entire lattice undergoing a complicated collective vibration that is a sum of all of these modes.